# Is there any way of exporting stored procedures with node.js mysqldump module

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

I work on an Electron App with Mysql and use the mysqldump module from npm site.
I save my database in the app with it and it's working fine for me. But I had to add some stored procedure and could't find any option with this module to get them in the dump. Did I miss something or no option for this is available?